# Split .TXT data as one column into 'n' itens in rows like CSV in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a .TXT file with a sequence of data like this:

```
Name: John Wick
Age: 34
Country: USA
Name: Jeffrey Jones
Age: 55
Country: Africa
```

And so on, big file. What I want is to put each set of data (Name, Age and Country) into separate rows, like a CSV file, like this:

```
Name: John Wick,Age: 34,Country: USA
Name: Jeffrey Jones,Age: 55,Country: Africa
```

I already tried this code, but I no output:

```
def chunker_list(seq, size):
    return (seq[i::size] for i in range(size))

with open('Data.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    print(chunker_list(f, 3))
```

This is the output:

```
C:\Users\marco\PycharmProjects\Convert2CSV\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/marco/PycharmProjects/Convert2CSV/main.py
<generator object chunker_list.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000021A73B3BB30>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, any idea on how I could achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by no output?

Comment: I edited the code to add the output.

Comment: You don't have any prints. What output do you expect to get without print?

Comment: Added the print command and still get no output

Comment: You did get output- the representation of a generator. For list comprehension, replace `(seq[i::size] for i in range(size))` by `[seq[i::size] for i in range(size)]`. (Though I still believe this is not the output you want. You should be more precise regarding what you expect)

Comment: I think I can´t be more precise than I have been. I have a big txt file with a one column data sequence as described and need to convert each 3 lines into one single row of Name, age and country. Changed the code as you suggested but got a Traceback error: return [seq[i::size] for i in range(size)]
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a loop, read three lines, remove their trailing newlines, and print them separated by commas.

```
with open('Data.txt') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            records = [next(f).rstrip('\n') for _ in range(3)]
        except StopIteration:
            break
        print(*records, sep=',')
```

Output:

```
Name: John Wick,Age: 34,Country: USA
Name: Jeffrey Jones,Age: 55,Country: Africa
```